# How to implement TextWatcher interface on Edit Text with Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, textwatcher

I am trying to implement an interface that will listen on my `EditText` when user types a single character on it such that when that happens I will get a Toast message that `You tried to type a new character` and when user clears then this interface will check the length of the characters inside the `EditText` and display a Toast message that you cleared all the text if the `count` is 0. This is where the `Android.Text.IWatcher` interface comes in. I have implemented it in my main class like this...

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity,ITextWatcher
    {
      //after I implemented the interface then these methods were generated by the compiler
       public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
           //check the length of characters typed and show a Toast
            if (s.Length() > 0)
            {
                
                Toast.MakeText(this, "You are typing more text", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
     //if user clears all text also show a Toast
            if (s.Length() == 0)
            {
               
                Toast.MakeText(this, "You have cleared all the text", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I assigned the Interface to my `EditText` like below.

```
               EditText user_message = chat_view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.message_box);
                //assign a text watcher to the EditText
               user_message.AddTextChangedListener(this);
```

The problem is that I do not get the Toasts when I type in my EditText when i debug this application to my android device, help me resolve this, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Create a TextWatcher class and then add this listener to the EditText.

```
 public class TextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {

    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------" + s);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout4);
        var editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        editText.AddTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher());
```

Comment: Already found a workaround but Thank You for your answer

Comment: Glad to help. Hope this way would help for you issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the C# event exposed on the `EditText` instead?

```
user_message.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
```

Then implement the method:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Text.Count() > 0)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to implement as you have suggested and see if I will get some results and mark it as accepted, @Cheesebaron

Comment: the view was inflated and am using the current activity class to call the Toast, could that be the reason why?

Comment: Use your debugger and narrow down what is going on. I cannot reproduce your issue...

Comment: Okay, I had to start a new Activity Intent for processing the edit Text event, Thanks for your help